# How to manipulate the value of variables based on an array of symbols in Julia?

Tags: metaprogramming, julia

This is somewhat related to David's question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999532/julia-changing-name-in-loop-using-symbolic-variables).  I'm interested in looping over an array of symbols (pointing to objects) and performing an operation on each step of the loop.  For example, suppose I want to write a function that looks at a bunch of variables and converts any scalars to one-element arrays.

```
widget = "a scalar"
dohickey = ["item 1", "item 2"]
gizmo = "another scalar"

theVariables = [:widget, :dohickey, :gizmo]
for thisVariable in theVariables
    if !(typeof(eval(thisVariable)) <: Array)
        println("Found a scalar")
        #Make it a vector here 
    end
end
```

Ideally at the end of this we would have the following

```
widget = ["a scalar"]
dohickey = ["item 1", "item 2"]
gizmo = ["another scalar"]
```

This is a fairly lame example, but how can this be done?  I thought I should be able to use something like

```
:($thisVariable) = [:($thisVariable)]
```

but I can't get it to work.

Edit: DSM's solution below works for the case described above, but in my actual usage I want to do this inside a function.  If I define

```
function getsort(; arga="", argb="", argc="")
    filterSpecs = [:arga, :argb, :argc]
    for ts in filterSpecs
        if !(typeof($ts) <: Array)
            #nothing here
        end
    end
end
```

and then call getsort() it throws

```
error compiling getsort: error compiling __getsort#31__: syntax: prefix $ in non-quoted expression
```

I'm clearly missing something about metaprogramming magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [code generation](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/#code-generation) section of the docs, I think all you need is

```
    @eval $thisVariable = [$thisVariable]
```

For example:

```
widget = "a scalar"
dohickey = ["item 1", "item 2"]
gizmo = "another scalar"

theVariables = [:widget, :dohickey, :gizmo]
for thisVariable in theVariables
    if !(typeof(eval(thisVariable)) <: Array)
        println("Found a scalar")
        @eval $thisVariable = [$thisVariable]
    end
end
```

which gives me

```
Found a scalar
Found a scalar

julia> widget
1-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "a scalar"

julia> dohickey
2-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "item 1"
 "item 2"

julia> gizmo
1-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "another scalar"
```

Comment: Ah nice!  I was trying to use eval but only eval() and not the macro version.

Comment: You could do it without the macro too, e.g. `eval(:(($thisVariable) = [($thisVariable)]))`, but that syntax makes it look more complicated than it really is.

Comment: I also noticed that this runs comically slow -- the example above takes a full three seconds to run.  However, if you run it a second time (so there are no scalars) it only takes 6 ns.  Is there any particular reason why this is true?  (Luckily only need to do this for three items in my real code).

Answer (score 4):

This is more a followup to @DSM's answer but writing code in comments is hard.  A word of caution: `eval` evaluates in the global scope which can lead to strange things

```
julia> a = 3
3

julia> function f(a)
         eval(:(a = 1))
         println(a)
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(a)
3

julia> a
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you need a macro here?  If you're looking to just handle your function inputs you can do something like:

```
julia> function newDictOfArrays(d)
         wrapped=false
         for (k,v) in d
           if !(typeof(v) <: AbstractArray)
             wrapped = true
             d[k] = [v]
           end
         end
         (wrapped, d)
       end
newDictOfArrays (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function f(; kwargs...)
         (wrapped, d) = newDictOfArrays(Dict(kwargs))
         if wrapped
           return f(;d...)
         end
         println("continue knowing all keyword args have been wrapped: $kwargs")
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(a=1, b=[2])
continue knowing all keyword args have been wrapped: Any[(:a,[1]),(:b,[2])]

julia> f(a=[1], b=[2])
continue knowing all keyword args have been wrapped: Any[(:a,[1]),(:b,[2])]
```

newDictOfArrays checks all members of a dictionary for values that are not subtypes of AbstractArray, and overrides that item with a wrapped value.  In f, if anything was wrapped, it re-calls the same function again with the new dictionary passed as keyword arguments.  No macros, eval, etc, although you could consider writing a macro that injects the code into f automatically if need this frequently.